# How to split the names in a string while discarding a word?

Tags: python, split

I want to split this string:

```
"Oscar Wilde, Sophocles,  and  Lin-Manuel Miranda"
```

to get this list (`'and'` is discarded):

```
["Oscar Wilde", "Sophocles", "Lin-Manuel Miranda"]
```

Comment: De you know how to split a string?

Comment: Code example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? What part of this is actually the difficulty - when you tried your code, what was the result, and how was the different from what you wanted? Did you try to use a search engine to find ways to solve the problem? What happened when you tried that? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_name_str = "Oscar Wilde, Sophocles, and Lin-Manuel Miranda"
cleaned_name_str = my_name_str.replace(", and ", ", ")

print(my_name_list)
# "Oscar Wilde, Sophocles, Lin-Manuel Miranda"

my_name_list = my_name_str.split(",")
print(my_name_list)
# ["Oscar Wilde", " Sophocles", " Lin-Manuel Miranda"]

clean_name_list = [i.strip() for i in my_name_list]

print(clean_name_list)
# ["Oscar Wilde", "Sophocles", "Lin-Manuel Miranda"]
```

There are several ways you can remove the and, this is just one.
The key things here are `split` which splits the string on a substring and `strip` which removes trailing and leading whitespace

The `[item for item in list]` bit is called "`list comprehension`" and is super powerful in python (there's also "`dictionary comprehension`") which is basically how filtering is done in python and can often clean up for loops.

Comment: Nice solution as well, however you might want to use directly `my_name_str.split(",")` in the comprehension, this avoid loading the whole list in memory (not critical here, but a good practice in general) +1 ;)

Comment: Also be careful of `i.replace(" and ", "")`, this might replace legitimate bits of text if " and " is in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Mozway excellent points -- I often try to balance optimized code with readable code when answering questions for new folks; I'll rearrange some things

Comment: @SUEN, FWIW I'd most likely use regex for this in production -- it's all preference at that point

Answer (score 1):

You could split using a regex:

```
s = "Oscar Wilde, Sophocles, and Lin-Manuel Miranda"

import re
out = re.split(',\s*(?:and\s*)?', s)
```

`',\s*(?:and\s*)?'` means a comma optionally followed by spaces and `and`.

Output:

```
['Oscar Wilde', 'Sophocles', 'Lin-Manuel Miranda']
```

Comment: Regex is also a nice solution; OP, if you're learning regex checkout `regex101.com` to test expressions easily

Comment: I'd consider `,\s(?:\s*and\s*)?` so drop the leading space in the second name

Comment: Good point, thanks @Schalton

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the "and" to a comma and `split` anywhere it finds a comma, and then iterate over the list to clear any whitespace around with the `strip.()`

```py
txt = "Oscar Wilde, Sophocles and Lin-Manuel and Miranda"

elem = txt.replace(' and ',',').split(',')
elem = [x.strip() for x in elem]
# print(elem): ['Oscar Wilde', 'Sophocles', 'Lin-Manuel', 'Miranda']
```

Comment: thank you, i tried this method but its not working for some elements of the list that looks like this  ['Oscar de la Renta and Janet Ruttenberg'], if i replace and with ' '

Comment: caption = caption.replace(' and ', ',').split(',') , replacing and with comma works on     ['Oscar de la Renta and Janet Ruttenberg'], but not on ["Oscar Wilde", "Sophocles", "Lin-Manuel Miranda"]). am new to python

Answer (score 0):

```
my_name_str = "Oscar Wilde, Sophocles, and Lin-Manuel Miranda"
my_name_split = my_name_str.split(' and ')
my_name_str = ''
for i in my_name_split:
    my_name_str += i
my_name_split = my_name_str.split(',')
print(my_name_split)
```